# Get IP addresses of all devices connected (UDP)

Tags: c, udp

I have looked for a similar question, but I could not find one that would work for me. I am doing a simple project for one of my subjects, but I never had experience with sockets, so I need some help with the implementation of one feature.

Basically, there are several units interconnected by a communication network (physical ETHERNET 1Gbps, TCP / IP protocol), and I have to be able to communicate with all the boards. I can implement all other features I need on one specific board, but I don't know how to manipulate all the boards simultaneously.

So, the question is: how to get a list of all boards connected and how to select which board should receive/send a message?

Big thanks to anyone who would help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "mzapo_parlcd.h"
#include "mzapo_phys.h"
#include "mzapo_regs.h"

#define MY_PORT 55555
#define BUFLEN 512


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  int sockfd;
  char buffer[BUFLEN];
  struct sockaddr_in peeraddr;

  // SET UP A NETWORK SOCKET
  if ((sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  int broadcast = 1;
  if (setsockopt (sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, & broadcast,
    sizeof broadcast) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt (SO_BROADCAST)");
    exit(1);
  }

  struct sockaddr_in bindaddr;

  memset(&bindaddr, 0, sizeof(bindaddr));
  bindaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bindaddr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
  bindaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  int yes=1;

  if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                sizeof(yes)) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt (SO_REUSEADDR)");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&bindaddr, sizeof(bindaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
  }

  broadcast = 1;

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast,
        sizeof broadcast) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt (SO_BROADCAST)");
        exit(1);
    }

  struct sockaddr_in braddr;  

  memset(&braddr, 0, sizeof(braddr));
  braddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  braddr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT );
  braddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;  

  strncpy(buffer, "Hello world", sizeof(buffer));

  char* ipString = inet_ntoa(bindaddr.sin_addr);

  while(1){

  printf("%s", ipString); 

  if (sendto(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&braddr, sizeof(braddr)) == -1){
      perror("sendto");
      exit(1);
  }

  peeraddr_len = sizeof(peeraddr);

  }  
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: There's really two questions here. To get a list of all boards on the LAN, you'll need to send a message to the broadcast address, have each board listen and send a response to this message, and wait for these responses on the machine you broadcast from. Because you're using UDP, you need to be prepared that not everyone will hear your broadcast, and not every response will make it back.
As for selecting which board should get a message, you should address packets to that specific board's IP address.

Comment: Ok, so if not everyone hears the broadcast, does it mean that I cannot list some of the boards on the LAN?

Comment: It won't happen often, it may never happen in 1000 tests. It's just that UDP doesn't guarantee delivery, so you shouldn't expect it to be 100% reliable.